# Use remote dedicated server as a networked drive - Map network drive for a public IP

Tags: windows, ip

With a dedicated server, is it possible to mimic the way in which a VPN networked drive works but on the public web?

My intent is to host a folder for Revit worksharing.

For instance, can I provide read/write access to a Revit file hosted on a publiclly accessible server with a static IP?

Ideally, I would be able to, on windows, map the networked drive. This is easy on a VPN or if you are on the same LAN, but can it be done with a static IP?

I want to do the same thing as below, but with a server instead of a VPN NAS.

[image: projects 192.168.254.17]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's possible. But your ISP must not block the SMB ports.
But it's not recommended because windows file sharing can be vulnerable. A more secure file-sharing solution over the internet would be an SFTP server that encrypts the file-sharing traffic.

The best option for file sharing is always using A VPN. You can deploy a Linux server with OpenVPN and then another SFTP server behind OpenVPN.

Comment: SSH (which is a basis for SFTP) is no less secure than VPN, it provides a VPN a-la OpenVPN itself, and it is really redundant to require VPN to run SFTP in it; it's like requiring VPN inside of VPN.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is good option if you're going to make a private share over Internet. To mount a SFTP share in Windows you can use [rclone with SFTP driver](https://rclone.org/sftp/). It allows to map SFTP share as a drive letter and is overall great software and it's maintained.

SSH which is a base of SFTP allows for key-based security and you can restrict a key you configure for share to only allow SFTP connections with that key (e.g. no port forwards, not shell). (The partial problem with this is it will still allow to edit away a restriction. It will not be the case if you create sftp-only user for it with chroot into directory which won't contain its own `.authorized_keys` file.)

The problem with SFTP is that it will be slow to show updates to other peers (if you mount the same remote on several machines). For the latter think of deploying WebDAV-based solution. SMB over VPN worked fine too, and this time it's really a good idea to use VPN to access samba share. OpenVPN or WireGuard will be easy to set up and that's probably more versatile solution for a bigger deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Webdav works well for that since it's accessed via HTTPS (so no issue having to get unusual ports opened by your ISP), allowing you to map a drive directly to the webdav folder path. On a Windows server we use HTTP Commander which works well. Integrates with AD for user authentication, drive mapping works well, or can allow users to access files via the web UI with it. Also has some handy extra features which may or may not be of use, like the ability to share a file with a 3rd party via a link, optionally password protected and time limited.

*There are plenty of alternatives including on Linux, but this is the only one I've got first hand experience of so can't be sure how much of this is standard webdav and how much is that specific implementation.*